# Video capture with Google Cardboard

Tags: android, video-capture, google-cardboard

I would like to know if it's currently possible to allowing capture video "flow" (flux) with Cardboard SDK and display it with some 3D objects in the presence of a NFC tag for example.

Sorry if my english is a little bad.

Comment: What do video capture and NFC tags have to do with the Cardboard SDK? I would imagine that you would capture video and scan NFC tags the same way as you would without Cardboard.

Comment: I would like to do something like the Nintendo 3DS does with the AR cards.

Comment: Nobody ? Maybe my question isn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

looking for how to add video to

```
public void onNewFrame(HeadTransform headTransform) {
    // Build the Model part of the ModelView matrix.
}
```